# Check mysql connect

Tags: php, mysql

In a class I have a method for establishing a database connection and also 3 different `a`,`b`,`c` methods.

Every `a`,`b`,`c` methods, need a database connection, so I am checking if mysql is not connected -  connect now, else do nothing. This is my code:

```
class myClass {
    public $DBisConnected = false;

    function db_connect () {
        $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db_name") or die("no conn");

        $this->DBisConnected = true;
    }

    function a () {
        if(!$this->DBisConnected) {
            $this->db_connect();
        }

        // here process for a
    }

    function b () {
        if(!$this->DBisConnected) {
            $this->db_connect();
        }

        // here process for b   
    }

    function c () {
        if(!$this->DBisConnected) {
            $this->db_connect();
        }

        // here process for c
    }
}
```

My question is: are there ways for checking if a database connection already exists? If so, how would I use them in my code?

Comment: declare the connection in constructor so you need not call it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your connect code in class constructor like this:

```
function __construct () {
     $this->db_connect();
}
```

Then you should store in the private bool variable the value true only if the connection goes fine (by checking connection function return value).

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass {


    public $DBisConnected = false;

    function db_connect () {
        if(!$this->DBisConnected) {
         $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db_name") or die("no conn");
         $this->DBisConnected = true;
        }
    }



    function a () {
           $this->db_connect();


        // here process for a
    }

    function b () {
            $this->db_connect();

        // here process for b   
    }

    function c () {
            $this->db_connect();

        // here process for c
    }

}
```

However it would be even better to just call db_connect() from constructor once and not everytime from every function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset()` to check if the `$this->db variable` is set or not. But your way is appropriate too. But just check `$this-db variable` and then assign a value to `$this->DBisConnected`.